# Why is this variable reassigned to 0?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that takes in an array, and renders components using `map()`. The issue is that the `index` value from `map()` seems to revert to 0 no matter what in the anonymous function associated with my `onChange` listener.

```
function Questions({ questions, answers, toggleAnswers }) {
  const questionButtons = questions.map((question, index) => {
    if (answers[index - 1] === undefined || answers[index - 1] === 'true') {
      const buttonIndex = index;
      console.log('BEFORE RETURN etv:', event.target.value, 'index:', index, 'buttonIndex:', buttonIndex);
      return (
        <CustomFormComponent
          key={ index }
          name={ question.substr(0,5) }
          label={ question }
          value={ answers[index] }
          handleChange={ (event) => {
            console.log('ISTHISEVER NOT ZERO?', buttonIndex);
            toggleAnswers(event, index);
           }
         }
        />
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      { questionButtons }
    </div>
  );
}
```

The punchline? It's *never* not zero. The initial render and console output:
[image]

```
BEFORE RETURN etv: undefined index: 0 buttonIndex: 0
```

And then after tapping the 'YES' button:

[image]

```
ISTHISEVER NOT ZERO? 0
BEFORE RETURN etv: true index: 0 buttonIndex: 0
BEFORE RETURN etv: true index: 1 buttonIndex: 1
ISTHISEVER NOT ZERO? 0
BEFORE RETURN etv: true index: 0 buttonIndex: 0
BEFORE RETURN etv: true index: 1 buttonIndex: 1
```

If I tap on either of the "NO" buttons, `buttonIndex` still equals 0.

Comment: There is no event yet when you log `BEFORE RETURN etv`. The variable `event` isn't available until you're inside your `handleChange` callback.

Comment: Yes, but my question concerns why `buttonIndex` stays zero even though the map's `index` is 1 in the second question. (I understand why `event` is undefined before you click on anything)

Comment: whats the handleChange handler? Where have you specified this? Or are you using some library, react-form? Can you drop the code for CustomFormComponent

Comment: It's in the parent component. It updates the parent's state with the `index` & value ("true"/"false") of the button clicked. The problem is that the `index`, even "frozen" `buttonIndex` seems to change to 0 in `handleChange`'s anonymous function despite being 1 before the return.

Comment: So in toggleAnswers(event, index), index always returns 0?

Comment: Yes, I verified by logging the inputs into `toggleAnswers`: there, `index` was verified to be zero, too (no matter what button I clicked).